# Flutter web: Convert CSV to list for

Tags: flutter, csv, flutter-web, csvtoarray

There is plenty example of CSV to list for flutter apps, I'm facing issues with flutter web and the conversion of the file.

Some CSV aren't working as desired, I guess that it's a formatting issue
Here is the converting function when a user upload a file

```dart
Future _openFileExplorer() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        allowMultiple: false,
        withData: true,
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['csv']);
    if (result != null) {
      //decode bytes back to utf8
      final bytes = utf8.decode((result.files.first.bytes)!.toList());
      setState(() {
        //from the csv plugin
        employeeData = CsvToListConverter().convert(bytes);
      });
    }
  }
```

**Working CSV file conversion**

[image: Working CSV file conversion],

**Not working csv file conversion, the structure isn't the same, it's a big chunck**

[image: Not working csv file conversion, the structure isn't the same, it's a big chunck],

I did a complete repo of the project if you want to try, added some photos in the README,

https://github.com/valentincx/csv_to_list_for_web

Answer (score 4):

You should add `eol: "\r\n",fieldDelimiter: ","` to `CsvToListConverter()`. your code will be like this:

```
employeeData = CsvToListConverter(eol: "\r\n",fieldDelimiter: ",").convert(bytes);
```

Comment: Added the code, it didn't change much for my case but thanks for the response! Some csv are formatted differently, as you can see in the git repo  `mock_data.csv` still doesn't work with this code. I decided to show an error when it's not working and specify that the user should send a specific format.